# Undefended Type "Auth" showing in IDE

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-8

`Undefended Type "Auth"` shows in the IDE as a potential error when using `Auth::routes()` in `web.php`.

..... Can you help me understand or solve it please?

[image]

Comment: Install https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper#installation to generate automatically a ide helper file that will stop this kind of errors in most IDEs

Comment: In this case, you should be able to use the `auth()` helper instead of the `Auth` facade. Also, in the future, do not post your code as an image. Code is Text, copy, paste and format it properly into your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67493678/edit

Answer (score 2):

Just add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` to the head of your file `web.php` if you do not want to see it in your IDE.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

...
```

The reason the app can pick it up is that it is defined as an alias in the `config/app.php` file.